# Is it ok to pass an OrderedDict as a Celery task argument?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery, ordereddict

I have inside a Django REST Framework's serializer **an overridden `update` method**.
In this `update`, as user can send lots of children, I have **an asynchronous Celery task `process_children`**, to deal with the kids.

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ....

    @transaction.atomic
    def update(self, mymodel, validated_data):
        try:
            children_data = validated_data.pop('children')
            transaction.on_commit(lambda: process_children.apply_async(
                countdown=1,
                args=[mymodel.id, children_data]))
        except KeyError:
            pass
        ...
```

In the args, there is one argument which **is not a `json` object but an `OrderedDict`**: `children_data`.

The task looks like:

```
@app.task
def process_children(mymodel_id, children_data):
    mymodel = MyModel.objects.get(pk=mymodel_id)
    children = mymodel.children.all()
    for child_data in children_data:
        try:
            child = children.get(start=child_data['start'])
            child = populate_child(child, child_data)
            child.save()
        except Child.DoesNotExist:
            create_child(mymodel, child_data)
```

### I read that we should only send `json` (or pickle, yaml, whatever...) args.

- But this setup seems to work
- I can even send `datetime` object (i.e. the `start` attribute I use in the task to match a stored child with new values sent through the api).

### So what's happening here?

- Is everything ok, celery serializes and deserializes OrderedDict like a boss.
- Or I am crazy and should serialize before invoking the task and deserialize inside the task?

### [UPDATE, adding CELERY settings]

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = get_env_variable('REDIS_URL')
CELERY_BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 0
CELERY_REDIS_MAX_CONNECTIONS = 10
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/London'
```

Comment: Have you tried to `dict(children_data)` so it is converted to a normal dict before being sent to the task?

Comment: Would it be better to use `dict` than `OrderedDict`? What would be the point as for now, everything seems to work in test and production? My question is more is it right or should I move to serializing and deserializing myself in `json`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the pickle serializer which will handle objects relatively well, but there are concerns with it. [Here's a blog post on the concept of serializing and celery.](http://oddbird.net/2017/03/20/serializing-things/)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to show my CELERY settings, I will add that but no I'm using `json` and never received a runtime error as explained in that blog article.

Comment: Weird. The ordered dicts might get serialized fine, but datetimes should break.

Comment: Yes and I also have Decimal fields :/

Comment: In the [Kombu doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/kombu/en/latest/userguide/serialization.html) it is explicitly said that `Date` and `Decimal` are not accepted. I will double check that pickle is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are doing it correct.

As mentioned in [doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.2.1/userguide/calling.html#serializers).

> Data transferred between clients and workers needs to be serialized, so every message in Celery has a content_type header that describes the serialization method used to encode it.

Also, from celery 4.0 default serializer is JSON (which was `pickle` earlier). So whenever you are calling this task celery by default is serializing and de-serializing it.
If you want to use any other serializer, then while calling task you need to specify `content-type` (if you are using `.delay` then by default serializer will be `json`.

```
process_children.apply_async((model_id, children_data), serializer='pickle')
```

Comment: Correct so long as int / etc keys are not used in the dict. The serialization to json coerces them to strings, because json only has strings as keys, which can be quite the shock the first time it happens.